# Changing directory in a CakeFile task

Tags: terminal, coffeescript, cd, cakefile

I tried to change the directory using a normal cd command, but it says execvp(): No such file or directory.

These are the lines:

```
fs = require 'fs'

util = require 'util'
{spawn} = require 'child_process'

clientTest = (callback) ->
  d = spawn 'cd', ['client']
  d.stderr.on 'data', (data) ->
    process.stderr.write data.toString()
  d.stdout.on 'data', (data) ->
    util.log data.toString()
  d.on 'exit', (code) ->
    callback?() if code is 0
```

I'm guessing I have to do something withe the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

`cd` is a built-in shell command. Try running

```
/usr/bin/cd /dir
```

from your shell; you'll find that it doesn't do anything. Likewise, running `cd` from Node has no effect.

Instead of spawning `cd`, you should change the working directory with [`process.chdir`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory).